# How to decode/inflate a chunked gzip string?

Tags: php, gzip, inflate, chunked

After making a gzip deflate request in PHP, I receive the deflated string in offset chunks, which looks like the following

Example shortened greatly to show format:

```
00001B4E
¾”kŒj…Øæ’ìÑ«F1ìÊ`+ƒQì¹UÜjùJƒZ\µy¡ÓUžGr‡J&=KLËÙÍ~=ÍkR
0000102F
ñÞœÞôÎ‘üo[¾”+’Ñ8#à»0±R-4VÕ’n›êˆÍ.MCŽ…ÏÖr¿3M—èßñ°r¡\+
00000000
```

I'm unable to inflate that presumably because of the chunked format. I can confirm the data is not corrupt after manually removing the offsets with a Hex editor and reading the gzip archive. I'm wondering if there's a proper method to parse this chunked gzip deflated response into a readable string?

I might be able to split these offsets and join the data together in one string to call gzinflate, but it seems there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper method to deflate a chunked response is roughly as follows:

```
initialise string to hold result
for each chunk {
  check that the stated chunk length equals the string length of the chunk
  append the chunk data to the result variable
}
```

Here's a handy PHP function to do that for you (**FIXED**):

```
function unchunk_string ($str) {

  // A string to hold the result
  $result = '';

  // Split input by CRLF
  $parts = explode("\r\n", $str);

  // These vars track the current chunk
  $chunkLen = 0;
  $thisChunk = '';

  // Loop the data
  while (($part = array_shift($parts)) !== NULL) {
    if ($chunkLen) {
      // Add the data to the string
      // Don't forget, the data might contain a literal CRLF
      $thisChunk .= $part."\r\n";
      if (strlen($thisChunk) == $chunkLen) {
        // Chunk is complete
        $result .= $thisChunk;
        $chunkLen = 0;
        $thisChunk = '';
      } else if (strlen($thisChunk) == $chunkLen + 2) {
        // Chunk is complete, remove trailing CRLF
        $result .= substr($thisChunk, 0, -2);
        $chunkLen = 0;
        $thisChunk = '';
      } else if (strlen($thisChunk) > $chunkLen) {
        // Data is malformed
        return FALSE;
      }
    } else {
      // If we are not in a chunk, get length of the new one
      if ($part === '') continue;
      if (!$chunkLen = hexdec($part)) break;
    }
  }

  // Return the decoded data of FALSE if it is incomplete
  return ($chunkLen) ? FALSE : $result;

}
```

Comment: Excellent, works just as expected. That is a handy PHP function indeed, I've been seeking this for awhile now. Much thanks!

Comment: @user1309276 I have updated the above function, it had an error surrounding the behaviour when the string contains a literal CRLF. This has now been fixed, and this has also provided better detection of malformed strings.

Comment: Thanks again! For anyone still having problems, after calling unchunk_string all I need to do is remove the first 10 bytes using: $data = gzinflate(substr($data,10));

Answer (score 3):

To decode a String use [gzinflate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php), Zend_Http_Client lib will help to do this kind of common tasks, its wasy to use, Refer [Zend_Http_Response code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Response.php#L352) if you need to do it on your own

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried the method that lib uses, but it does contain some code I might need in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution from user **@user1309276** really helped me! Received from the server a gzip-compressed json response with `transfer-encoding: chunked` header. None of the solutions helped. This solution works like magic for me! It just remove the first 10 bytes.

```
$data = json_decode(gzinflate(substr($response->getContent(), 10)), true);
```